# no wrap (head) vs onLoad

Tags: javascript, loops, dojo, onload

In this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R7n2q/), i got different outputs, if i use (no wrap) or (onLoad).

My question is, in html file, to get a correct alert: 1,2,3,4 what alteration is needed in code ? With a simple load of dojo i got always 4 in all alerts:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var slider = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        slider[i] = function () {

            alert([i]);

        };
        dojo.addOnLoad(slider[i]);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```
var slider = [];

for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

    slider[i] = (function (i) {

        return function () { alert([i]); }

    })(i);
    dojo.addOnLoad(slider[i]);
}
```

This will save `i` into another functions scope saving the state. Without the closure, `i` is scoped to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

The value of i is 4 at the end of the loop, which is what your functions will see when they are called. Something like this should work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var slider = [];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    eval("slider[i] = function () { alert([" + i + "]);};");
    dojo.addOnLoad(slider[i]);
}
</script>
```

Edit: well you could also try doing the counting when the functions are called rather than when they're defined. e.g.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var slider = [];
var onLoadCounter = 0;

var onLoadCallback = function() {
    alert(onLoadCounter);
    onLoadCounter++;
};

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    slider[i] = onLoadCallback;
    dojo.addOnLoad(slider[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is the unique alternative? If so, I will get a big eval (there is more code)

Comment: Don't use `eval`. It is slow and hard to debug.